# Print_r not working in php

Tags: php, html, arrays, forms

i am trying to pass an array in form using a hidden element in php. I first create the array then then are foreach which runs through each element in the loop, next I echo a html type with type hidden that will be in my form. Last I want to print out the hidden form element using print_r

Here is my code

```html
<?php

$postvalue=array("a","b","c","e", "f", "g");
foreach($postvalue as $key => $value)
{
  echo '<input type="hidden" name="result[]" value="'. $value. '">';
}



print_r($_POST['result']);

<?
```

When I run this code I get the following error from the print_r

> Notice: Undefined index: result

How do I fix this?

Comment: `$_POST['result']`? from where this came suddenly in your code?

Comment: `$_POST` data is only set after a form has been submitted by e.g. clicking on a submit button.

Comment: What do you do? I cant see an `<form>` here? And there is no magic that makes a form from one `<input>` !?

Comment: Also _Life Cycle of a HTML Form_ `$_POST` wont exist untill the form has been Submitted. That `print_r()` need to be placed in a test that checks if the form is being submitted OR is just being sent for the first time to the browser

Comment: You are receiving that error because in this given code the `$_POST['result']` does not exist yet, like others have mentioned the form would have to post this to the page first for it to exist

Comment: oh right so how do I print the input then?